# Compile-time checking of Boost.Format

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-warnings, static-analysis, boost-format

Both Clang and GCC can check printf-style functions for mismatches between their format strings and their arguments.  For example, they'll complain about statements like this:

```
printf("Hello, %s!\n");
```

Does anything similar exist for [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/)?  In other words, are there any compiler switches, static analysis tools, etc. that can warn about code like

```
std::string s1 = str(boost::format("Hello, %s!"));
```

or

```
std::string s2 = str(boost::format("Hello, %s!") % "John" % "Doe");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is not supported 
A ticket has been created on boost as well to track it. 
You may want to pick up trunk version if you really need it.

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6815

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Boost Format but the [{fmt} formatting library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which is similar in spirit but uses Python-like format string syntax provides compile-time checks.

For example:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

std::string s = format(FMT_STRING("{2}"), 42);
```

gives a compile-time error because the format string refers to argument 2 which was not provided.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt}